# How to Get Current (US) State from iPhone Core Location?

Tags: iphone, xcode, geolocation, core-location

I'd like my iOS app to display information specific to the user's current state (i.e. California, Oregon, etc). How is this done using core location? The CLLocation class has coordinates—how do I turn that into the state? (FYI I don't need more detail such as city or street)

Answer (score 4):

Use the Google Maps API reverse geocoding.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

Comment: Argh! Why can't I format a comment? Hmph. (see my supplied answer)

Answer (score 3):

As Brad mentioned, you can use Google (or Mapquest, et al) to obtain Reverse Geocode information. Google offers data in XML, JSON, or CSV. So, you could use a URL like:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=LATITUDE,LONGITUDE&output=csv&sensor=true
```

So, http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=37.032978,-95.620834&output=csv&sensor=true would put you in Coffeyville, KS, and you can grab the info from there.

FWIW, if you are using MapKit, you can also use the MKReverseGeocoder to obtain an MKPlacemark.